# Need a regex that makes sure the number starts with 01 02 or 08 and is 10 or 11 digits long

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

Am having hard time crediting a regex to check if a number starts with `01`, `02` or `08` and is ten or eleven digits long.

For example I want numbers formatted like this to pass:

```
01614125745
02074125475
0845895412
08004569321
```

and numbers other forms to fail, number like:

```
0798224141
441544122444
0925456754
```

and so on. Basically, any number that does not start with `01` `02` or `08`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following pattern follows the criteria:

```
/^(?=\d{10,11}$)(01|02|08)\d+/   # This pattern can easily be extended

/^(?=\d{10,11}$)0[128]\d{8,9}/   # Same effect
```

Explanation:

```
^                Begin of string
(?=\d{10,11}$)   Followed by 10 or 11 digits, followed by the end of the string
(01|02|08)       01, 02 or 08
\d+              The remaining digits
```

Comment: An explanation of the parts in the regex would make the answer evenbetter. Especially when using non capturing groups and greedy quantifiers other than ? and * as those are exotic feature to most developers.

Comment: I would've just done `/^(01|02|08)\d{8,9}$/`, but this works too and could be more flexible later.

Comment: @Wiseguy I saw: "10 or 11 digits long, starting with ...". For this reason, I decided to suplly a pattern which can easily be re-used and extended (what if the following criteria is added: `or starts with 112`) ;)

Comment: Thanks that worked great am i right in say if i have/^(?=\d{10,11}$)(01|02|08|03|07)\d+/
it will mean it allows 03 and 07 as well ? if so that's great massive help thank you

Comment: @user1053865 Yes, that works as well. If the prefixes are of a fixed size, you can also use the following pattern (although, for an unexperienced user, its effect is not as obvious as the previous pattern): `^0[12378]\d{8,9}$` (= *START* `0` *one of* `12378` *8 or 9 digits* *END*).

Answer (score 12):

Rob W's answer is correct. But I'd use a simpler expression like this: (No need for lookahead)

```js
/^0[128][0-9]{8,9}$/
```

Comment: Why would someone downvote this answer? It is simple, fast and accurate. Go figure...

Comment: Great answer. Helped me to see other ways to construct regex for this task.